# Python Pygsheet creating PERCENT_STACKED bar chart

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, pygsheets

I'm trying to create a horizontal PERCENT_STACKED bar chart from n rows of data stored in a google sheet using Python.
Currently, I am using Pygsheet and am able to create a chart using:

```
wks1.add_chart(('A4','A6'), [('B3','B6'),('C3','C6')], 'Title')
```

This creates a COLUMN chart, currently, I've read through Pygsheets [documentation](https://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/worksheet.html#pygsheets.Worksheet.add_chart) and the [Google API documentation](https://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/chart.html#) (linked on Pygsheets) but have not found anything explaining how I write my code to use different chart types specifically PERCENT_STACKED, I have tried to update chart_type= but I have only gotten errors when adding this value. Any ideas on how to go about changing the chart type?

Also I tried setting the chart to be horizontal is another area I haven't had any luck with.

Answer (score 0):

pygsheets currently dosent support specifying stackedType. The property you are looking for is [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/charts#basicchartspec). For your case, pygsheets will need to add stackedType property [here](https://github.com/nithinmurali/pygsheets/blob/2fa7df15dedb7ea8e0fa8b49647004e2f225b32d/pygsheets/chart.py#L272). So you can either modify the pygsheets source or can use the [custom request](https://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spreadsheet.html#pygsheets.Spreadsheet.custom_request) to create a chart by sending the [chart-create request](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#addchartrequest).